# error: no such partition Grub Error

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

This problem seems different than what others have posted on here. I'm using a ThinkPad laptop with Windows and Debian dual booted. After a normal day of use on Debian, the next day I booted the computer and got:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Most tutorials say to boot up a live version of Debian, and then run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

When I do so, however, I get

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=245764094): Input/output error
```

Followed by the disk information.
Ignoring this warning, I continue with the tutorials:

```
sudo mdkir /mnt/temp
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/temp
```

Upon running the second line, I get the error:

```
mount: /mnt/temp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Is my hard drive bad? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you do an abnormal or forced shutdown? Or major Windows updates? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Nope, nothing out of the usual, just normal web browsing/Rails development. Running that command gives `Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is unable to even read a partition table from the disk.

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=245764094): Input/output error
```

This suggests very strongly that your drive is probably bad.

The output of `smartctl -x /dev/sda` would be useful in further analysis.

The recommended "fix" would be to replace the disk with a new one, and restore from backup.

But if you don't have a good backup, or had important data on the disk that was not backed up yet, you will need to consider whether it's worth the money to involve a professional data recovery service or not. If the answer is yes, **stop** trying to recover data yourself: you might be making the problem worse by just running the disk.

If the data on the disk is not valuable enough to pay for a professional recovery, but you still would like to recover whatever you can, a good first step would be to use the `ddrescue` tool to make an exact 1:1 clone/image of the whole disk. You would obviously need a second disk, or otherwise enough unused disk space for the disk image file.

Once that is done, you could try programs like `testdisk` or `photorec` for recovering your files (ideally using the clone/image you created earlier, so if something important cannot be recovered easily, the original failed disk will still be available for another attempt).

`testdisk` would be good at reconstructing the partition table; if the filesystems within the partitions are still mostly intact, this might be all you would need.

`photorec` on the other hand is designed to pull individual files with identifiable structure out of a disk whose filesystem structure is lost. If the damage is not limited to the partition table, this might be needed.

Comment: There's no important information on the disk. How does this sort of thing happen? Normal wear and tear? I don't move it from the desk. The output of `smartctl -x /dev/sda` is quite lengthy, not sure how I would show that here...

Comment: All I know is if drive is seen as good or bad. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools &  What a Failing HDD looks like
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2446974